# Splitting long line printed to screen the right way in python

Tags: python, pep8

This might be a silly question but I'd like to know how other people handle this or if there's a standard/recommended way of going about it.

Below are two approaches to splitting a long text line when printing it to screen in python. Which one should be used?

**Option 1**

```
if some_condition: # Senseless indenting.
    if another condition: # Senseless indenting.
        print 'This is a very long line of text that goes beyond the 80\n\
character limit.'
```

**Option 2**

```
if some_condition: # Senseless indenting.
    if another condition: # Senseless indenting.
        print 'This is a very long line of text that goes beyond the 80'
        print 'character limit.'
```

I personally find **Option 1** ugly but **Option 2** seems like it would go against the pythonic way of keeping things simple by using a second `print` call.

Comment: Personally, I'd use triple quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it can be with parenthesis:

```
print ('This is a very long line of text that goes beyond the 80\n'
       'character limit.')
```

Of course, there are several ways of doing it. Another way (as suggested in comments) is the triple quote:

```
print '''This is a very long line of text that goes beyond the 80
character limit.'''
```

Personally I don't like that one much because it seems like breaking the indentation, but that's just me.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a long string and want to insert line breaks at appropriate points, the `textwrap` module provides functionality to do just that. Ex:

```
import textwrap

def format_long_string(long_string):
    wrapper = textwrap.TextWrapper()
    wrapper.width = 80
    return wrapper.fill(long_string)

long_string = ('This is a really long string that is raw and unformatted '
               'that may need to be broken up into little bits')

print format_long_string(long_string)
```

This results in the following being printed:

```
This is a really long string that is raw and unformatted that may need to be
broken up into little bits
```